# Blueberry Plant is Sick or just Overwatered?

Tags: diseases, leaves, watering, containers, blueberries

I'm a newbie and could use some help.

So I just got my first blueberry bushes and am very excited, but one of the bushes (Jubilee Southern Highbush) is showing some concerning signs. The leaves are rather dry, and are curling upward. Then this morning they started showing these strange browning / yellowing patterns. I have had them about a week and watered this one twice, the second time because the leaves looked so dry. But now I'm worried I overwatered it. Read online that it could also have to do with the PH levels being too high. If anyone has any input or advice it would be greatly appreciated!

It is an indoor plant but I live in the coastal southwest US and it has been somewhat warm the last few weeks. The soil an inch down feels close to dry right now.

If any more info is needed I'm happy to reply to comments or add to the post!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The plant is not well but overwatering could not kill it this quick. However, the acid soil they need is already the soil you bought them in and didn't move them out of.

Comment: ...assuming, of course, it was in good acid soil mix as purchased. That's not a reasonable pot for a blueberry plant to live in - they are shallow rooted and that's a narrow/deep pot for the plant top we can see, if you are not transplanting it out into the world shortly after purchase. Indoors is not a great place for blueberries, they want a lot of strong sun to be happy.

Comment: It may be too late by now to ask more questions. How many other blueberry plants do you have? Are you treating them the same as far as watering and sun? Are they doing well?

Answer (score 1):

Zero idea what's wrong.

In Your shoes - and if I insisted on it surviving - I would

- repot it into larger pot while preserving all the original soil (water just before as to keep the soil together, fill the larger container with whatever soil but leave a hole exactly the size of this pot, extract the plant+soil and drop gently as to destroy the minimal amount of roots)
- in no case increase sun exposure
- water more frequently
- keep other plants at a distance
- keep fingers crossed.

But those are just the thoughts of a plant murderer - take them with a bag of salt.

The larger pot would allow for root expansion and moisture retention. The damage can't be fungal if the air is dry. I have no idea what sunburn looks like. Curved leaves are not visible on the photos.